# Hide only one element in fixed div when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this big photo which takes 100%x100% of screen size and above it there is fixed slider.

I want to fadeout (hide) this green logo when you scroll down from this big header photo leaving navigation bar without it.

How can I do that?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiUfE.jpg here is photo

Comment: Can you post more code about what you have done?

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uenbk6uk/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the logo to scroll with the page, just put it outside of the menu bar in your HTML and use position absolute ([JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uenbk6uk/1)).

If you want it to fade out once it leaves the slider, you can use jQuery, here is an example:

```
//Some variables, to avoid calculating these values at every scroll
var logo = $('#logo');
var sliderBottom = $('#slider').offset().top + $('#slider').height() - logo.height();

//On every scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
    // if we're past the slider and the logo is still visible
    if($(window).scrollTop()>sliderBottom && logo.is(':visible')){
        logo.stop().fadeOut(300);
    }
    // if not
    else if($(window).scrollTop()<sliderBottom && logo.is(':hidden')){
        logo.stop().fadeIn(300);
    }
});
```

### JS Fiddle Demo